# Auto-scheduler support for Hexagon

Tags: halide

How can I use auto-scheduler for Hexagon DSP or any target that is not supported? Also, are you planning to support auto-scheduling for Hexagon soon?

Answer (score 0):

The auto scheduler might already work for Hexagon standalone use, but it will not automatically insert Hexagon offload calls. It is planned to support GPU scheduling in the auto scheduler and that will possibly address this, but the timeframe is a bit open as there's some work to be done on increasing the power of the auto scheduler first.